# create robot model for rviz

Tags: rviz, urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can convert a model of the robot from any CAD(AutoCAD, Inventor, 3d max etc.)? For example pr2 was somewhere drawn, or described it "by hand"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12548/create-robot-model-for-rviz/) by [Grem](https://answers.ros.org/users/1608/grem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out [Simmechanics to urdf](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simmechanics_to_urdf)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you looked at the [urdf tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials) ? These explain the creation of a urdf model comprehensively.

Short answer: For the different links (e.g. "parts") of your URDF model you can use either built-in primitives like cylinders, boxes etc. or a mesh in .stl or .dae (COLLADA) format. Meshes in these formats can be created/exported using a multitude of 3D modeling solutions, like AutoCAD, Inventor, 3DS Max, Blender, Sketchup or others. The safest bet is probably to export a plain .stl file at the beginning, as COLLADA meshes sometimes seem to have problems with exporting due to being more complex.

You can also check the http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_description package (install it on your machine) and have a direct look at the PR2 urdf files.

It should also be noted that visualization in rviz is only one of multiple uses of a URDF model. Having a URDF model of your robot for example also makes it easy to transform data between different coordinate systems or to simulate the robot in gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-01-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4